# \jetified-media2-widget-1.1.1\res\values\values.xml:258:5-266:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/viewType' with config ''

Tags: android

I suddenly get this

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource compilation failed
> C:\Users\ZANJI.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\564f4d5f24f2a167c473c2b001cdbd3f\jetified-media2-widget-1.1.1\res\values\values.xml:258:5-266:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/viewType' with config ''.

and its pointing to;

```
 <declare-styleable name="VideoView">
        <!-- Default : true -->
        <attr format="boolean" name="enableControlView"/>
        <!-- To choose underlying view type to render a video. Default : surfaceView -->
        <attr format="enum" name="viewType">
            <enum name="surfaceView" value="0"/>
            <enum name="textureView" value="1"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
```

from
`...\jetified-media2-widget-1.1.1\res\values\values.xml` (Don't even know what this is for)
please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Turns out chaos.PinView had an `attr/viewType` that was conflicting with the `attr/viewType` of VideoView. Hence could not compile correctly. So i just removed the PivView dependancy. (Sad! i really loved that pinView)